# can not setup passwordless ssh using key by MANUALLY COPY public key to server

Tags: 20.04, ssh, openssh

context:

- firstly, i got a new ubuntu 20.04 server with a password
- I'm using OpenSSH client on Windows 10
- I want to do passwordless login, then I

  - ssh to server using passwords,
  - manually create `~/.ssh /authorized_keys` and open it in `vim`
  - copy&paste my public key content from my `C:\users\me\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` to ssh window.
  - exit that ssh session and try to passwordless login,
  - failed
- (some more tries and many headbang)
- I install Git Bash On Windows, then run `ssh-copy-id` and got another identical line in `authorized_keys` on the server
- now I could successfully passwordless login to server

**Why this happen? Does `ssh-copy-id` do more thing than just insert a line in `(server) ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?**

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting. Public keys don't need to be redacted. All that said, are the lines really identical? How did you paste it into Vim?

Comment: The lines have different length, it should be easy to see they're not identical.

Comment: @muru I paste into vim using `shift insert`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, I will check it again

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, it's all my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at both entries in your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. The first entry starts with `sh-rsa`, whereas your second starts with `ssh-rsa`. That’s most likely the problem. So when you copy/pasted your public key, you simply made a typo.